# What is scope of jpf controller?

Tags: java, weblogic

I am new to weblogic and I am trying to migrate one jpf annotation based application to Spring. I want to know what is default scope of jpf controller. I googled but I am unable to find the scope of it.

Currently I am keeping scope of my spring controller as Session, and using member variables of page flow as it is. As per testing I have done, it is working fine. But I am not sure whether it will create some issue on prod or not.

Thanks